# Delete method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, autocomplete, delete-row, bloomberg, autofilter

I have some code where I am using index(match) based on a cell with a dropdown menu. When users select a certain security, a CUSIP is outputted which then pastes formulas from bloomberg to output the data into excel.

I then proceed to create a table but would like to filter the table using autofilter and delete the rows that dont meet the filter criteria but that doesnt seem to be working for some reason! I also have insrted an activex control form button so that when a user double clicks on the dropdown menu they can search for a security and it would autocomplete.

Please help, Thanks!

```
Sub INDEX_MATCH_CUSIP_TO_SHORTDESCRIPTION()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B3:E100").Delete

 Range("B2").Select
 test = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("DEX Spread Report (Corp)").Range("B7:B1600"),           Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell.Value, Sheets("DEX Spread Report (Corp)").Range("D7:D1600"), 0), 1)
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = test

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 End Sub

Sub BBRG_FORMULAS_FOR_SECURITY()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim CUSIPS As String

    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Range("B2").Select

 CUSIPS = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value

ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = "=BDS(""" & CUSIPS & """ & ""& CUSIP"",""ALL_HOLDERS_PUBLIC_FILINGS"", ""STARTCOL=1"", ""ENDCOL=1"")"
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Value = "=BDS(""" & CUSIPS & """ & ""& CUSIP"",""ALL_HOLDERS_PUBLIC_FILINGS"", ""STARTCOL=6"", ""ENDCOL=8"")"


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub


Sub Create_Table_and_AutoFilter()

 Dim wksDest As Worksheet
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim rng     As Range
 Dim rngDelete As Range

Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Set wksDest = Worksheets("Sheet4")

 LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
 LastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row

 ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(LastRow, 5)), , xlYes).Name = "HoldersTable"

With wksDest
Set rng = Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(LastRow1, 5))
rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=1000"
Set rngDelete = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rng.AutoFilter
rngDelete.EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you're most probably trying to delete table header

try substituting the code from `With wksDest`to `End With` with the following snippet:

```
With wksDest.Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(LastRow1, 5))
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=1000"
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(,1)) > 1 Then .offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

Comment: It told me no cells were found. The cells in my table disappeared after stepping through .Autofilter Field:=1...

Comment: The correct range should be: With wksDest.Range("B4", Cells(LastRow1, "E"))

Comment: @markos: it's because my code checked for (counted) visible cells number in _all_ range so that it also counted all header cells which are always visible and there are four of them. See edited code where I added `.Resize(,1)` to count visible cells in range first column. Sorry for the mistake. BTW `wksDest.Range("B4", Cells(LastRow1, "E")) ` and `wksDest.Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(LastRow1, 5))` return the same range